# How to call function with T& when i have both T& and T as return type of functions with same name

Tags: c++

I have a class with two functions named Select and return type of T and T&. i need to call function with T& but it always call function with return type T. 
How can i force it to call function with T& as return type.

Here is two functions

```
template <class T>
T Array2D<T>::Select(const int& row, const int& column) const
{
    if ((row*this->columns_) + column < 0 || (row*this->columns_) + column >= this->storage_.Length())
    {
        AdtException exception("Index Out of Bound");
        throw exception;
    }
    return this->storage_[(row*this->columns_) + column];
}

template <class T>
T& Array2D<T>::Select(const int& row, const int& column)
{
    if ((row*this->columns_) + column < 0 || (row*this->columns_) + column >= this->storage_.Length())
    {
        AdtException exception("Index Out of Bound");
        throw exception;
    }
    return (this->storage_[(row*this->columns_) + column]);

}


Here is calling code.
template <class T>
T& Row<T>::operator[](const int& column)
{
    T t = this->arr_.Select(row_, column);
    T& t1 = t;
    return t1;
}

template <class T>
T Row<T>::operator[](const int& column) const
{
    return this->arr_.Select(row_, column);
}
```

Here are the interfaces

```
class IRow
{
public:
    virtual ~IRow() = default;
    virtual T& operator[](const int& column) = 0;
    virtual T operator[](const int& column) const = 0;
};

class IArray2D
{
public:
    virtual ~IArray2D() = default;
    virtual T Select(const int& row, const int& column) const noexcept(false) = 0;
    virtual T& Select(const int& row, const int& column) noexcept(false) = 0;
    virtual Row<T> operator[](const int& row) const noexcept(false) = 0;
    virtual Row<T> operator[](const int& row) noexcept(false) = 0;
    virtual explicit operator bool() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual size_t Rows() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual size_t Columns() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void Rows(const size_t& rows) noexcept(false) = 0;
    virtual void Columns(const size_t& columns) noexcept(false) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Do you ever use the shown `operator[]` on the left-hand side of an assignment?

Comment: Besides that you have a fatal flaw in the function returning a reference: The variable `t` is a *local* variable that will end its life-time with the function, and you return a reference to that local variable. You should do just `return this->storage_[(row*this->columns_) + column];` like you do in the other function.

Comment: Your `operator []` should also have a `const` overload, but you only have a non-const version.  You realize that your code using `[ ]` will not compile if called on a const `Row` object, right?  Does your test program do this: `void foo(const Array2D<int>& x) { x[0]; }` or something similar to that, and attempt to call `foo`?  You'll see what I mean if you attempted something like that.

Comment: I have updated my question please check @Someprogrammerdude  but its still not working, now if i call a.select(row,col) = 5; it changes the current value at that index by 5 but when i call a[row][col] = 3; it does not change the current value at that index by 3.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sir i have that operator overloaded i just didn't add it here in question. i have updated my code in question. kindly check.

Comment: @AmmadIslam Please look at how [the subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) is implemented for `std::vector`, as that works correctly.  You should be returning either a reference or const reference.  How else will your value be updated if you're not returning a reference?  When you return a value, you're changing copies, not the actual object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes sir i understand that it should be returning reference not copied values that's why i need to call the other Select method with T& but its always calling Select with T. i have to implement both of methods as it is necessary to follow exact structure as define in interface.

Comment: You made the same mistake in your `operator []` as you did with `Select`, and that is returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: You have just moved the error into the `operator[]` function, as you return a reference to a local variable there now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sir if i use following
 return this->arr_.Select(row_, column);
it says cannot convert from T to T& because it is calling select function that is returning T not T&

Comment: Let's start from square one, and ask a simple question -- why are you returning objects instead of references all the time?  If the user of your class wants copies, then they can do this by simply calling your function, and on the left side of the `=`, they specify an object instead of a reference.  There is no need for you to handhold and try and return objects back to the caller -- they have full control over that.  Again, how does `vector` work flawlessly, and your class doesn't work?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> v1 = {"abc"}; std::string s; s = v1[0];`  The user gets a copy of the string, even though `[]` for vector returns a reference. Why?  Because the user wanted to make a copy by specifying a non-reference on the left side.  If the user wanted a reference: `std::string& s = v[0];`.  You should follow good practices and actual real-life examples on how to implement subscript operators correctly.  Your implementation attempts to go against this, and you're fighting with getting it to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sir by returning objects if you mean using T as return type of function . I have to use implement it as its part of interface that this class is implementing and i cannot change it. I have updated my code and included interfaces. i will be very thankful if you look at code again and tell me a solution to my problem.

Comment: Why not just **completely remove the first implementation** of `Select` (the one that returns a copy of the item) and be done with it?  And then apply the fixes as other have suggested around returning references to stack variables.

Comment: @selbie -- Exactly.  If the user (the person using the class) wants copies, then they can have copies by assignment.  There is no need for the class itself to force copies on the user.

Comment: @selbie sir as i explained in above comment that i cannot change interface so i cannot remove implementation of Select. my question has definitions of interfaces. kindly have a look at them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sir as i explained in above comment that i cannot change interface so i cannot remove implementation of Select. my question has definitions of interfaces. kindly have a look at them

Comment: @AmmadIslam -- That first implementation adds nothing, as I've stated many times already, copying is controlled by the *user* of the class -- the class need not be involved.  Who put that implementation there in the first place?  At the very least, are you understanding what we're saying, instead of just accepting bad code?

Comment: I received header files from my professor and he mentioned to follow exact header files as provided. i totally agree with you about removing first implementation but the restriction of following exact header file doesn't let me do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally methods can't be overloaded based on the return type because there is no way for a caller to specify which overload he wants. In your case, however, the methods are overloaded using qualifiers: one `const` another isn't. Which means that in order to call the `const` version you need to call the method on the `const` object and opposite goes for the non-`const` version. For example:

```
// this will call the T Select(...) const because the array is const
static_cast<const Array2D<T> &>(_arr).Select(_row, column);
```

Comment: Sir the arr_ variable is declared as following and i cannot change it.
const IArray2D<T>& arr_

I have to call the non const method with it. please tell me how i can do that.

Comment: @AmmadIslam, in that case this is a design flaw because you can't call a non-const method on the const object. Of course you can cast away the const-ness like this `const_cast<IArray2D<T> &>(_arr)` but this is a **very bad practice and should be avoided** at any cost and I doubt this is what your professor would want. This seems like an error in the exercise if this `arr_` member is the part of the code that you can't change, unless it is the point of the exercise - to discover this error.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. you are a life savior.

Comment: *Thank you very much sir. you are a life savior* -- And at the same time, your professor is a C++ job killer.  If you plan on trying to get a C++ job with this poor way of being taught, you're in trouble.

Comment: yes sir i understand but its assignment and i have to do it to pass.